# From Name - This is a user-friendly name that is displayed to your recipient when they receive their email

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates, sendgrid-api-v2

Is there any restriction in SendGrid to use numbers in the "user friendly name" in the From field for easy identification?

For example: Would like to use "123456" pravar@pravar.com instead of "Pravar" <pravar@pravar.com". However, when I use number, unable to relay such emails with the following error.

"The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved"

But when I change the number to the name, the mail delivery works normal. The sender verification has been completed with domain authentication in our case.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't used the same friendly name when you did the [Single Sender Verification](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification#form-fields).

Does it work when you complete this form with the same name, i.e. number?